# add to a double in C#

Tags: c#

im making a "fake" Vacation planning guide 
it asks the user to select a place then a activity they wish to do 
i cant seem to make it add a decimal total like 199.99 in this case to a global total 
what am i doing wrong here?

//this is all in the public main class by the way

```
double Total = 0.00; 
string destination = Console.ReadLine();

int Destination = Convert.ToInt16(destination);

switch (Destination)
{
    case 1:
    {
        Console.WriteLine("you have selected Barbados! Heres the following excursions you can do!");
        Console.WriteLine("_________________________!Excursions!_________________________________");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Snorkeling in Barbados bay: $199.99 Per Person");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1");
        Console.WriteLine("Barbados Tour Bus Adventure: $59.99 Per Person");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 2");
        Console.WriteLine("Barbados Shopping Extravanga: $199.99 Per Person");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 3");
        Console.WriteLine("_________________________!Excursions!_________________________________");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("What is your choice?");

        string barbadosanswer = Console.ReadLine();
        int barbadosAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(barbadosanswer);

        switch(barbadosAnswer)
        {
            case 1:
              Total + 199.99;
            //heres where id add to Double total but it wont allow me to it needs a declaration that it is being added?
            Console.WriteLine("You have selected Snorkeling in Barbados bay! Your total is currently " + Total);

             break;
        }
```

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to add 199.99 to the total.

Comment: so what you want is a representation of double value as a string?

Comment: We have no context for that code, but it doesnt looks like Total is global at all.  And you'll want to at least read the error message... *needs a declaration that it is being added* is not a real error

Comment: Try changing `Total + 199.99;` to `Total += 199.99;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind your price package to `Total`.

```
double Total = 0.00; 
        string destination = Console.ReadLine();

        int Destination = Convert.ToInt16(destination);

        switch (Destination)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you have selected Barbados! Heres the following excursions you can do!");
                    Console.WriteLine("_________________________!Excursions!_________________________________");
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Snorkeling in Barbados bay: $199.99 Per Person");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press 1");
                    Console.WriteLine("Barbados Tour Bus Adventure: $59.99 Per Person");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press 2");
                    Console.WriteLine("Barbados Shopping Extravanga: $199.99 Per Person");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press 3");
                    Console.WriteLine("_________________________!Excursions!_________________________________");
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    Console.WriteLine("What is your choice?");

                    string barbadosanswer = Console.ReadLine();
                    int barbadosAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(barbadosanswer);

                    switch(barbadosAnswer)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Total += 199.99;
                            Console.WriteLine("You have selected Snorkeling in Barbados bay! Your total is currently " + Total);

                        break;
                    }
```